# Alternatives to ngSwitch on constructor.name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototypal-inheritance

In my current project I have to deal with many types of `Categories`. Each category has to be rendered in a different way, and has different functionalities.

In order to achieve this, I created a `Category` factory which acts as a "base class" in my model. In this way, I can extend/override `Category` behavior (e.g, by defining a `MultiCategory` which contains subcategories).

The problem comes when I try to have each category type render differently: in order to do so, I defined a directive:

`<div ng-repeat="category in data.categories" category="category"></div>`

In my design, the directive would switch on `category.constructor.name` to decide how to render itself:

```
<div class="container" ng-switch="category.constructor.name">
    <div ng-switch-when="MultiCategory"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

However, when I tried to do this, AngularJS threw an error at me, because it doesn't allow `constructor.name` expressions. (Related to security)

I found a workaround by implementing a function

```
Category.prototype.getType = function() {
    return this.constructor.name;
}
```

The switch then becomes:

```
...ng-switch="category.getType()"...
```

See an example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/daw2q/5/).

So far it's working ok, but I'm not really comfortable with this approach. It required me to pollute `Category.prototype`, and if there are security concerns in using `constructor.name`, I would like to address them.

So my question is: **can anyone come up with a better approach**?

**EDIT:**

Comments/answers focus on the use of ngSwitch, but that is not the issue raised by this question. I'd still have the same problem by using

`ng-if="category.constructor.name"`

The point is: **What is the best approach to determine the type of my model objects that doesn't require restorting to `constructor.name`?** Do I really need to pollute my model with a `type` property or a `getType` method?

Comment: How differently do the different types need to be rendered? Have you thought about using ng-show to conditionally show pieces of one large template based on the properties your looking for from your extended types?

Comment: @AndrewChurch that's not the point, I would still need to check the type of category somehow. I improved the question, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help you to see how i'm doing it. I've a base-class called [stdClass](https://github.com/platdesign/stdClass).

In your case i would do s.th. like:

```
var Category = stdClass.extend({
    constructor:function(attrs){
       this.attrs = attrs || {};
    },
    getType:function(){ return this.type; }
});

var CategoryA = Category.extend({ type:'A' });
var CategoryB = Category.extend({ type:'B' });
```

Now create new Models and push them to an array:

```
var collection = $scope.items = [];

var model = new CategoryA({name:'Peter'});
collection.push(model);

var model = new CategoryB({name:'Paul'});
collection.push(model);
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'A'">Category A: {{item.attrs.name}}</div>
    <div ng-if="item.type == 'B'">Category B: {{item.attrs.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Maybe this will help you. Do not hesitate to ask more... =)

Comment: So you basically have a type specified for each constructor function, as in my workaround. Well, since there is apparently no better solution, I will stick with this. Nice approach with this `stdClass`!

Comment: You don't need a constructor function for each type. You could also have one "Category"-Class, construct it and then set the type...

Comment: Yeah, I guess my approach suffers because of my background of static OO languages, the flexibility of javascript's prototypal inheritance still scares me a little.

Answer (score 1):

ng-switch is not the best tool for your case. It is intended for things like "tab-bars".
In your case i would prefer

```
<div ng-repeat="category in data.categories">
    <ng-if="category.type == 'exampleTypeA'"></div>
    <ng-if="category.type == 'exampleTypeB'"></div>
    <ng-if="category.type == 'exampleTypeC'"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Please, see my edit. The point of the question is not the choice of the directive, but rather how to use/design the model properly.

Comment: why do you think it would pollute your model?